# Why is document.execCommand("paste") not working in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, clipboard

I have a problem with my extension. I want to paste data from the clipboard.

So far, I've got this:

```js
function pasteAndGo()
{
    document.execCommand('paste')
    alert("Pasted")
}
```

The alert comes up, but nothing has been pasted.

I've got a feeling it's the `document` part that needs changing, but I don't know what to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you executing this code?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://farter.users.sourceforge.net/blog/2010/11/20/accessing-operating-system-clipboard-in-chromium-chrome-extensions/

Comment: This code is being executed on a regular webpage, not background.html. However, this is no longer an experimental API, and a built in part of Chrome as of version 13 (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/whats_new.html#13) This means it should work now. Also, I have added the permissions for it :)

Comment: How can you grant permissions to a regular webpage?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There used to be an experimental clipboard API in Chrome, but this was removed in Chrome 13.

Chrome has moved towards the more standard `document.execCommand('paste')`, `document.execCommand('copy')` and `document.execCommand('cut')` commands:

- [Rich-Text Editing in Mozilla](http://web.archive.org/web/20210725074947/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla) - MDN Docs (Archive)

In Chrome you'll need permissions need to be added to your manifest: "clipboardRead" and "clipboardWrite".

- [Declare permissions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html) - Chrome Docs

Up until Chrome 38, these clipboard permissions were only available to extension pages such as background scripts. As of Chrome 39, content scripts can also use these clipboard APIs after declaring the clipboard permissions in the manifest file.

- [`clipboardRead/clipboardWrite` permissions are not respected in content scripts](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395376) - Chromium Issue (#395376)

Comment: update-- here's the link: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html

Comment: 2022 update: here's the link: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/permission_warnings/

Answer (score 20):

Calling `document.execCommand("paste")` is not supported by "reasonable" browsers, because of security concerns as it might enable the script to read sensitive data (like passwords) from the clipboard.

This is the **compatibility matrix** of `document.execCommand("...")` concerning clipboard events:

|  | "copy" | "paste" | "cut" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **IE** | OK | OK | n/a |
| **Edge** | OK | n/a | OK |
| **Firefox** | OK | n/a | OK |
| **Chrome** | OK | n/a | OK |

**My two cents to this:**

- The behaviour of *Edge*, *Firefox* and *Chrome* is "reasonable" as they prevent pasting/reading data from the clipboard. They do enable cut, as cut is simply a copy followed by a delete.
- The behaviour of *IE* makes no sense to me, as it enables the "risky" paste, but does not execute the cut event.

You can **feature detect** the possible commands using the [document.queryCommandSupported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/queryCommandSupported) method.

**Edit:** According to MDN `document.queryCommandSupported` is now deprecated and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 9):

This works well for me in a background page.

```
function getClipboard() {
    var pasteTarget = document.createElement("div");
    pasteTarget.contentEditable = true;
    var actElem = document.activeElement.appendChild(pasteTarget).parentNode;
    pasteTarget.focus();
    document.execCommand("Paste", null, null);
    var paste = pasteTarget.innerText;
    actElem.removeChild(pasteTarget);
    return paste;
};
```

Of course your extension still needs "clipboardRead" permission and you have to use message passing to get this information back to your content script:

## content.js:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({
    cmd: "clipboard", //$NON-NLS-0$
    action: "paste" //$NON-NLS-0$
}, function(response) {
    if (response.paste) {
        var range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();
        range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(response.paste));
    }
});
```

## background.js:

```
function getClipboard() {
    var pasteTarget = document.createElement("div");
    pasteTarget.contentEditable = true;
    var actElem = document.activeElement.appendChild(pasteTarget).parentNode;
    pasteTarget.focus();
    document.execCommand("Paste", null, null);
    var paste = pasteTarget.innerText;
    actElem.removeChild(pasteTarget);
    return paste;
};

function onClipboardMessage(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action === "paste") { //$NON-NLS-0$
        sendResponse({
            paste: getClipboard()
        });
    }
}

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(onClipboardMessage);
```

Comment: @peter-ehrlich Hi Peter, how about this example? Is it what you were asking for?

Comment: Hi @josephduffy did you get this to work? Did you example help?

Answer (score 2):

You can't execute it on a regular page, only in a background page.

Comment: Do you do the whole invisible textarea thing? Anyone have a code sample?

Comment: not true anymore, see answer below ('as of chrome 39, content scripts can also use these clipboard APIs after declaring the clipboard permissions in the manifest file')

Comment: An example of an background page?

Comment: What is a "regular page" vs. a "background page"?

Comment: @brandaemon Indeed, this means nothing

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `clipboardRead` permission to use `document.execCommand('paste')` and the `clipboardWrite` permission to use `execCommand('copy')` and `execCommand('cut')`.
Otherwise, the permissions will be denied and nothing will happen.

Check [this](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions) link for more details.

Answer (score 1):

you need to a control in focues which is capable of receiving the content...

For some examples regarding clipboard in JS see http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial126_Clipboard-cut-copy-and-paste-with-JavaScript.html
and http://help.dottoro.com/ljcvtcaw.php

Regarding Chrome extensions see [Copy/Paste Not Working in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925073/copy-paste-not-working-in-chrome-extension/6934850#6934850)

Comment: That's the exact page I found my information form (The link to the other Stack Overflow question). I'll try and work on getting it to paste in the right area? :S

Comment: you need to have the focus on something that can accept what is in the clipboard - like a textarea when the clipboard contains text...

Answer (score 1):

You can mimic a paste by doing the same thing yourself by hand:

1. Optional: trigger when the user tries to paste
2. Get the contents of the clipboard (requires permission from user via a pop-up the browser will provide)
3. Insert content into the active control
4. Optional: trigger the events a real paste would have triggered (for the benefit of any listeners)

Focusing on steps #2 and #3 first, in this example, I check whether the active element is a text input.  If so, I simulate a paste by replacing that text box's highlighted content and repositioning the cursor.

```
function myPaste() {
  navigator.clipboard.readText()
    .then(clipText => {
      const el = document.activeElement;
      if (el.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
        const newCursorPos = el.selectionStart + clipText.length;
        el.value =
          el.value.substring(0, el.selectionStart) +
          clipText +
          el.value.substring(el.selectionEnd);
        el.setSelectionRange(newCursorPos, newCursorPos);
      }
    });
}
```

For #1, add a listener to intercept the user's paste attempts:

```
addEventListener("paste", pasteHandler);

function pasteHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  myPaste();
}
```

For #4, add this after `el.setSelectionRange(newCursorPos, newCursorPos);`:

```
el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

Note that if you are using a reactive framework that manipulates the DOM on your behalf based on data binding, you will need to defer the cursor position update until after the next DOM render.  For instance:

```
Vue.nextTick(() => {
  el.setSelectionRange(newCursorPos, newCursorPos);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because on manifest v3 does not work with service worker, I found a better solution after long researches: (You still need to set the clipboardRead permission in manifest)

```
navigator.clipboard
        .readText()
        .then(
            (clipText) => console.log(clipText)
        );
```