# the proper use of execcommand("paste") in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to paste clipboard data into a textarea using `execcommand("paste")` with a chome extension, but i cannot seem to get it to work. 
permissions are set. 
I have tried to set `focus()` on the textarea, but `document.execCommand("paste")` does nothing, and I get no error.
calling `execcommand("paste")` from background page also does nothing.

```
<form>
     <textarea id="ta"></textarea>    
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.findElemetById("ta").focus();
    document.execCommand("paste");
</script>
```

Comment: Small observation, but did you mean `document.getElementById` as `document.findElementById` doesn't exist? I'm sure this isn't the problem with your real code as this would definitely cause an error.

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969403/cant-get-execcommandpaste-to-work-in-chrome/7100464#7100464

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Clipboard functionality is a key part of [my extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/template/dcjnfaoifoefmnbhhlbppaebgnccfddf) so I've seen all the normal problems. On my background page I expose a `copy` and a `paste` function and the page itself contains `<textarea id="sandbox"></textarea>`;

```
function copy(str) {
    var sandbox = $('#sandbox').val(str).select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    sandbox.val('');
}

function paste() {
    var result = '',
        sandbox = $('#sandbox').val('').select();
    if (document.execCommand('paste')) {
        result = sandbox.val();
    }
    sandbox.val('');
    return result;
}
```

I'm using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for simplicity but you get the idea. Now any time I want to use the clipboard functionality I simply call the relevant function. Other pages in my extension can access this API via [chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getBackgroundPage) but you can also use [chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(callback)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage) if your background page is an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).

I'm not sure if this is best practice or if such a thing even exists for this functionality yet but this definitely works for me and is very clean.

Comment: thank you very much
I could'nt get your code to work out of the box, but changing
    result = sandbox.val();
to
    result = $("#sandbox").val();
did the trick

Comment: Ah, lifesaver! Had a problem where I had copied some other code that used a textarea style='display: none;' which stopped it working but this does the trick perfectly!

Comment: make sure you have your permissions set as well. "permissions": [ "clipboardWrite" ]

Comment: Hello, today 07/21/2015, document.execCommand('copy') works fine without extensions, but document.execCommand('paste') doesn't work. Do I need still the extension?

Comment: very good and working answer.. but i was trying to figure out what exactly are you using the sanbox for .. can you explain more about this thanks

Comment: can someone show an example without jQuery? perhaps link to a github gist? that would help

Comment: And also need to make sure that it is not hidden using something like `display: none;`. I used a few other ways to hide it like `opacity`, `width` and `height`.

Comment: without jQuery: https://gist.github.com/srsudar/e9a41228f06f32f272a2

Answer (score 20):

This is too long for a comment on Alasdair's excellent response, so I'm creating another answer. Alasdair's answer is excellent and worked great for me, but as a newcomer to Chrome extensions it still took me a while to get it working. For anyone in a similar position, here is an expansion on his answer.

Background/event pages are able to interact with the system clipboard, provided you've requested the appropriate permissions. They are not able to interact with the DOM of pages the user has loaded. Content scripts cannot interact with the system clipboard, but they can interact with the DOM of pages the user has loaded. Take a look at the [explanation of the extension architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) for a good overview of all this.

This essentially means you need to do the copy/paste actions from the system clipboard in your event/background pages, which is what Alasdair has outlined above. Any pasting or copying from the DOM of the page the user is viewing has to occur in your content script. The two scripts are able to communicate pretty easily with [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

I have [an extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/biotool/aenbjmfdhgnlpnpiiinajokpgchogmee) whose only purpose is to paste, and the architecture came largely from this post. If you want to see the above technique in practice, [take a look at the code](https://github.com/srsudar/biotool). In particular, [background.html](https://github.com/srsudar/biotool/blob/2e460ce17bb96828f6912ff9eaf2fd6051ae0dc4/app/background.html), [background.js](https://github.com/srsudar/biotool/blob/2e460ce17bb96828f6912ff9eaf2fd6051ae0dc4/app/scripts/background.js), and [contentscript.js](https://github.com/srsudar/biotool/blob/2e460ce17bb96828f6912ff9eaf2fd6051ae0dc4/app/scripts/contentscript.js).

If you're in a real hurry, [here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/srsudar/e9a41228f06f32f272a2).

Answer (score 0):

```
  function PasteString() {
    var editor = document.getElementById("TemplateSubPage");
    editor.focus();
  //  editor.select();
    document.execCommand('Paste');
}

function CopyString() {
    var input = document.getElementById("TemplateSubPage");
    input.focus();
   // input..select();
    document.execCommand('Copy');
    if (document.selection) {
        document.selection.empty();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
}
```

Hope this will work for you