# Button to get image from clipboard using web app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, clipboard, google-drive-api

I created chrome webapp to access the clipboard data.After added my webapp I have the permission to access the clipboard, but I don't know how to get the image from clipboard by clicking the paste button in my page. I just tried to paste an image in google drive presentation file.It shows to install the GoogleDrive webapp.After installing GoogleDrive webapp it allows us to get the image/text from the clipboard by clicking the paste button in edit menu.I want to know how Google Drive get clipboard data using paste button.

Comment: It looks like you need a NPAPI plugin for this at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [request the clipboardRead permission](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#permissions), you can use `document.execCommand("paste")`.

A good explanation for how to do that is https://stackoverflow.com/a/7147192/689161

**Edit:** some sample code

background.html

```
<div id="idk" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

background.js

```
function paste() {
    var div = document.getElementById("idk");
    div.focus();
    document.execCommand("paste");

    // you can now access whatever was pasted through div.innerHTML
    console.log(div.innerHTML);
}
```

If the user pastes an image, it'll show up as something like `<img src="..."/>` and you can extract that for use in your application.

Comment: Hi gengkev, thank you for your response. I already tried this code, but it only useful to get clipboard text not images. Have I missed something?

Comment: I think if you use a contenteditable, you can paste images, too. Does your application already handle pasting using Ctrl+V?

Comment: Yes, I already done pasting using Ctrl+V in HTML5.Your code works perfectly.Thank you for valuable response gengkev.