# execCommand not working in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, clipboard, google-nativeclient

I am using paste execCommand to get the system clipboard data.

```
document.execCommand("Paste", null, null);
var paste = pasteTarget.innerText;
```

I am trying to read data in every one sec delay, but `pasteTarget.innerText` is always returning null.

I am executing the above code **in the handle message from native client**. It seems this code is not executing on background page. How to execute the code in background page?

I am using the pepper API example(nacl_sdk\pepper_35\examples\api\input_event).

**common.js**

```
function getClipboard() {
            var pasteTarget = document.createElement("div");
            pasteTarget.contentEditable = true;
            var actElem = document.activeElement.appendChild(pasteTarget).parentNode;
            pasteTarget.focus();
            document.execCommand("Paste", null, null);
            var paste = pasteTarget.innerText;
            console.log("paste = " + paste);
            actElem.removeChild(pasteTarget);
            return paste;
    };
```

Whenever right button is clicked I am trying to get the clipboard data. But always `null` is returned.

**manifest.json**

```
    {
  "name": "Input Event",
  "version": "35.0.1916.114",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "35.0.1916.114",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Input Event Example",
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCMN716Qyu0l2EHNFqIJVqVysFcTR6urqhaGGqW4UK7slBaURz9+Sb1b4Ot5P1uQNE5c+CTU5Vu61wpqmSqMMxqHLWdPPMh8uRlyctsb2cxWwG6XoGSvpX29NsQVUFXd4v2tkJm3G9t+V0X8TYskrvWQmnyOW8OEIDvrBhUEfFxWQIDAQAB",
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "903965034255.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "clipboardWrite",
    "clipboardRead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you focus on the target first? See if this resolves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144702/the-proper-use-of-execcommandpaste-in-a-chrome-extension

Comment: I have the focus for that element. I am using the above  in the handle message from native client. It seams it is not executing  on background page.

Comment: The question needs more of your code then, perhaps.

Comment: sorry i am new to javascript, i will update the question with my code

Comment: What kind of element is `pasteTarget`?

Comment: I copied the getClipboard function from one of the stack overflow question.

Comment: Do you have the `"clipboardRead"` permission declared?

Comment: I have the permission. if i use the same code in background page it is working fine.

Comment: Can you tell more about where this code is, show the native client side, show the manifest?