# clipBoard using chrome api execCommand

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am using chrome extenstion and want to implement cut copy paste command . In my project i am using canvas . I want to use execCommand function for this . when i implement 
    document.execCommand('copy') and then paste it does not work . i have also changed permission in manifest file . can anybody tell me how this command will work .
i tried link http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial126_Clipboard-cut-copy-and-paste-with-JavaScript.html but document.selection.... is not working undefine error come ?

Comment: Before asking a new question please learn to accept atleast some answers for your previous questions if they helped you.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969403/cant-get-execcommandpaste-to-work-in-chrome

Comment: It works . Let say  I execute command document.execCommand('cut') . Now i want to store this cut value into variable  Is there any function for this or i have to make HTML object .

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same question.