# Is it possible to fully mimic clipboard functionality using the chrome extension APIs?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, clipboard

## Subject:

I'm in the process of creating a chrome extension and, for certain features, I would like to copy some text to the clipboard and automatically paste it into whatever element has the focus for the user.

Getting my text into the clipboard is no problem. I can simply create a `textarea` in my background page, set its value accordingly and then select it's contents. Then, I can use `document.execCommand("copy");`

---

## Problem:

The problem comes when I try to use `document.execCommand('paste')` in my content script. It works fine on simple text areas (like the one I'm typing in now). However, on many sites, it tends not to work. This typically happens when the editable element is inside an `Iframe`, or is actually a custom `<div>` rather than a vanilla `<textarea>`/`<input>`

Even though my trivial attempt fails to work in these cases, the built-in `paste` option that is provided by Google, works every time without fail.

Is it possible for a chrome extension to mimic this functionality in a customized context menu option? If so, how can this functionality be achieved?

---

## Additional Info:

This operation is invoked when a context menu option is clicked. Said context menu option is only visible when the element currently in focus is categorized as `editable` by the [`chrome.contextMenus` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus)

---

## Similar Questions:

None of these provided me with a satisfactory answer

- [the proper use of execcommand("paste") in a chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144702/the-proper-use-of-execcommandpaste-in-a-chrome-extension)
- [clipBoard using chrome api execCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792139/clipboard-using-chrome-api-execcommand?rq=1)

Comment: Not sure why you would use copy-paste - it's more of a user mechanism than a coding one.  The more common solution is to read the value you need into a variable, message it to the content scripts, which then inject it into the input field.