# document.executeCommand('paste') not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I add a mouse right contextMenu in my web site, which contains function(cut,copy,paste). I used document.executeCommand(). cut and copy can work. but paste no working in chrome(it is working in IE). How can i fix this question.

Comment: this might not work because of security concern, this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969403/cant-get-execcommandpaste-to-work-in-chrome talk about chrome-extension and need some clipboard  permissions to use it

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this doesn't work.  But all is not lost.  You can capture the contents of the clipboard from the paste event.

I wrote about it here:
http://blog.dmbcllc.com/cross-browser-javascript-copy-and-paste/

And there is a github here:
https://github.com/DaveMBush/CrossBrowserCopyAndPaste

This is all straight javascript that works in IE, FF, and Chrome (that I've tested)

```
(function () {
var systemPasteReady = false;
var systemPasteContent;

function copy(target) {
    // standard way of copying
    var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
    textArea.setAttribute('style','width:1px;border:0;opacity:0;');
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.value = target.innerHTML;
    textArea.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}

var textArea;
function paste(target) {

    if (window.clipboardData) {
        target.innerText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
        return;
    }
    function waitForPaste() {
        if (!systemPasteReady) {
            setTimeout(waitForPaste, 250);
            return;
        }
        target.innerHTML = systemPasteContent;
        systemPasteReady = false;
        document.body.removeChild(textArea);
        textArea = null;
    }
    // FireFox requires at least one editable 
    // element on the screen for the paste event to fire
    textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
    textArea.setAttribute('style', 'width:1px;border:0;opacity:0;');
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();

    waitForPaste();
}


function systemPasteListener(evt) {
    systemPasteContent = evt.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    systemPasteReady = true;
    evt.preventDefault();
}

function keyBoardListener(evt) {
    if (evt.ctrlKey) {
        switch(evt.keyCode) {
            case 67: // c
                copy(evt.target);
                break;
            case 86: // v
                paste(evt.target);
                break;
        }
    }
}


window.addEventListener('paste',systemPasteListener);

document.getElementById('element1').addEventListener('keydown', keyBoardListener);
document.getElementById('element2').addEventListener('keydown', keyBoardListener);
})();
```