# How do I select the last character of a string, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, select, cjk, execcommand

I have a function that gets the last character of a string the user types in an `input`. But how do I select that single character, using `execCommand()`? The goal is to copy it into a different `input`.

I tried `element.select()`, but with no results.

The character to paste into the new `input` must be the character visible in the original input, and not the character correspondent to the keyboard key the user types, since the reason for all this is having an external JS library handling some CJK character conversion in one `input`, and moving the result to a different one..

I am going with a copy-paste approach. Hence, the need to select the character. But if there is a better way to achieve it, feel free to tell me about it.

I am open to both Vanilla JavaScript and jQuery approaches.

This is my code:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toawqprj/)

```js
function copyPaste () {
  var i1 = document.getElementById('userInput');
  var i2 = document.getElementById('input2');
  var c = i1.value.substr(lol.length - 1);
  c.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  i2.focus();
  document.execCommand('paste');
  i1.focus();
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 255px;
}
  
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="First, type something here.">

<button type="button" onclick="copyPaste"();>Then, click here to copy the last character<br>of the above input into the next input.</button>

<input type="text" id="input2" value="Some text...">
```

Comment: Why do you want to use the clipboard for this? Why not just read the value from the first input, and use it to put its last character in the second? Also, `execCommand` is an obsolete feature...

Comment: Paste is [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53448633) nowadays

Comment: @trincot How would I do that?

Comment: I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use [`execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) as it is obsolete. Moreover, you don't need to use the clipboard to transfer a (part of a) string to another input box. This can be done with standard string handling:

- You can use `slice(-1)` to get the final character.
- I would also prefer `addEventListener` instead of the `onclick` attribute (where you had a typo also).
- With `+=` you can append the extracted character:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('userInput');
var output = document.getElementById('input2');
var btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  output.value += input.value.slice(-1);
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 255px;
}
  
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="First, type something here.">

<button type="button">Then, click here</button>

<input type="text" id="input2" value="Some text...">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It does make more sense to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

html:

```
<input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="First, type something here.">
<button type="button" onclick="copyPaste()";>Then, click here to copy the last character<br>of the above input into the next input.</button>
<input type="text" id="input2" value="Some text...">
```

js:

```
function copyPaste () {
  var i1 = document.getElementById('userInput');
  var i2 = document.getElementById('input2');
  var c = i1.value.slice(i1.value.length - 1);
  i2.value = c;
}
```

Used `slice()` to get the last character of the string. Note I also fixed the `onclick` handler in your html.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it replaces everything that was already in the second `input`. I need to keep its previous value.