# How to create copy-paste event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a copy-paste event from the console. Here is what I did till now:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

var copybutton = document.createElement('button');
copybutton.id = 'copybutton';
copybutton.innerHTML = 'Copy';
body.appendChild(copybutton);

var pastebutton = document.createElement('button');
pastebutton.id = 'pastebutton';
pastebutton.innerHTML = 'Paste';
body.appendChild(pastebutton);

var copyarea = document.createElement('textarea');
copyarea.id = 'copyArea';
copyarea.innerHTML = 'text1';
body.appendChild(copyarea);

var pastearea = document.createElement('textarea');
pastearea.id = 'pasteArea';
pastearea.innerHTML = '';
body.appendChild(pastearea);


// Here will be the function codes


document.getElementById('copybutton');
document.getElementById('pastebutton');
```

I created 2 text areas and 2 buttons. What I do want to do is, I want to copy the text inside of the text1 area with clicking the **copy button** and paste it inside of the '' area with clicking the **paste button**.

Comment: You've done the setup but not really attempted the main part of what you're trying to do. All you need to do is shovel one textarea value to another - there's no actual copy/paste/events going on so it's quite simple. Have a go...

Comment: Hi, @Mitya thanks for commenting out. The problem is, I could not write a good code for the paste function :/

Comment: The paste function should do the following: 1) grab the `value` of the first textarea; 2) set the `value` of the second textarea (with the grabbed value from step 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this snippet `copy` works fine but in Chrome you will need to set the clipboardRead permission to use `document.execCommand('paste')`

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969403/why-is-document-execcommandpaste-not-working-in-google-chrome?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

var copybutton = document.createElement('button');
copybutton.id = 'copybutton';
copybutton.innerHTML = 'Copy';
body.appendChild(copybutton);

var pastebutton = document.createElement('button');
pastebutton.id = 'pastebutton';
pastebutton.innerHTML = 'Paste';
body.appendChild(pastebutton);

var copyarea = document.createElement('textarea');
copyarea.id = 'copyArea';
copyarea.innerHTML = 'text1';
body.appendChild(copyarea);


var pastearea = document.createElement('textarea');
pastearea.id = 'pasteArea';
pastearea.innerHTML = '';
body.appendChild(pastearea);


// Here will be the function codes


var copyBtn = document.getElementById('copybutton');
var copyText = document.getElementById('copyArea');
var pasteBtn = document.getElementById('pastebutton');
var pasteText = document.getElementById('pasteArea');



copyBtn.addEventListener('click', copyFunction)

function copyFunction() {
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/
  document.execCommand("copy");
}

pasteBtn.addEventListener('click', pasteFunction)

function pasteFunction() {
  pasteText.focus();
  document.execCommand("paste");
}
```

Comment: Hi @ozgur, it is a really good answer but the paste button does not seem works :(